# How to figure out if I'm the message is sent to self? in AST (clang, objective c)

Tags: objective-c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I'm traversing Abstract Syntax Tree and encounter method call
`[self.view backgroundColor] = UIColor.redColor;`

How can I figure out if I'm sending a message to `self` or to some other object(it may super class, some property, doesn't matter).

I found a method which, according to its name, return a receiver to the message.

`Expr * getInstanceReceiver ()` It returns the object expression (receiver) for an instance message, or null for a message that is not an instance message.

And now from this Expr* I need to understand if it's self or not.
Does anyone has any ideas how to that?

Comment: have you looked at `isMemberOfClass:`, an NSObject protocol?

Comment: @danh I'm not writing code in objective c, I'm traversing AST of the objective c program, so I don't have objective c methods available to me, only clang's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this simple program in a file "main.m":

```
int puts(const char *);

__attribute__((objc_root_class))
@interface Robot
@property char *model;
@end

@implementation Robot
- (void)say:(char *)x {
    puts(x);
}
- (void)hello {
    [self say:"hello"];
}

- (char *)model {
    return "49209192";
}
- (void)whoAmI {
    puts(self.model);
}

- (void)setModel:(char *)model {
    puts("setModel test");
}
- (void)setModelTest {
    self.model = "123";
}
@end

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

You can print out the AST with this command:

```
clang -cc1 -ast-dump main.m
```

And then see that the "hello" method AST looks like this:

```
| |-ObjCMethodDecl 0x7fe1c905bdb0 <line:21:1, line:23:1> line:21:1 - hello 'void'
| | |-ImplicitParamDecl 0x7fe1c90806e8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit used self 'Robot *'
| | |-ImplicitParamDecl 0x7fe1c9080748 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit _cmd 'SEL':'SEL *'
| | `-CompoundStmt 0x7fe1c90808a0 <col:15, line:23:1>
| |   `-ObjCMessageExpr 0x7fe1c9080868 <line:22:5, col:22> 'void' selector=say:
| |     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe1c9080838 <col:6> 'Robot *' <LValueToRValue>
| |     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fe1c90807a8 <col:6> 'Robot *' lvalue ImplicitParam 0x7fe1c90806e8 'self' 'Robot *'
| |     `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe1c9080850 <col:15> 'char *' <ArrayToPointerDecay>
| |       `-StringLiteral 0x7fe1c9080808 <col:15> 'char [6]' lvalue "hello"
```

So "self" is an implicit first parameter to the "hello" method, and it is parsed as a **DeclRefExpr** inside a method call - ObjCMessageExpr, but also wrapped in an ImplicitCastExpr.

For a property access it looks different. The AST part for the "model" property access inside "whoAmI" function is contained inside a **PseudoObjectExpr**:

```
`-PseudoObjectExpr 0x7fe844080640 <col:10, col:15> 'char *'
  |-ObjCPropertyRefExpr 0x7fe8440805e0 <col:10, col:15> '<pseudo-object type>' lvalue objcproperty Kind=PropertyRef Property="model" Messaging=Getter
  | `-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe8440805c0 <col:10> 'Robot *'
  |   `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe844080578 <col:10> 'Robot *' <LValueToRValue>
  |     `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fe844080550 <col:10> 'Robot *' lvalue ImplicitParam 0x7fe844080468 'self' 'Robot *'
  |-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe8440805c0 <col:10> 'Robot *'
  | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe844080578 <col:10> 'Robot *' <LValueToRValue>
  |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fe844080550 <col:10> 'Robot *' lvalue ImplicitParam 0x7fe844080468 'self' 'Robot *'
  `-ObjCMessageExpr 0x7fe844080610 <col:15> 'char *' selector=model
    `-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe8440805c0 <col:10> 'Robot *'
      `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe844080578 <col:10> 'Robot *' <LValueToRValue>
        `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fe844080550 <col:10> 'Robot *' lvalue ImplicitParam 0x7fe844080468 'self' 'Robot *'
```

You also have the same **DeclRefExpr** for "self" here wrapped in a ObjCMessageExpr (or also ObjCPropertyRefExpr), but now there's an additional layer of wrapping - OpaqueValueExpr.

For a property setter call in "setModelTest" method it is even more involved:

```
`-PseudoObjectExpr 0x7fe844080b80 <line:27:5, col:18> 'char *'
  |-BinaryOperator 0x7fe844080ae8 <col:5, col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue '='
  | |-ObjCPropertyRefExpr 0x7fe844080a98 <col:5, col:10> '<pseudo-object type>' lvalue objcproperty Kind=PropertyRef Property="model" Messaging=Setter
  | | `-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080a78 <col:5> 'Robot *'
  | |   `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe8440809c0 <col:5> 'Robot *' <LValueToRValue>
  | |     `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fe844080998 <col:5> 'Robot *' lvalue ImplicitParam 0x7fe8440808d8 'self' 'Robot *'
  | `-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080ac8 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue
  |   `-StringLiteral 0x7fe844080a48 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue "123"
  |-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080a78 <col:5> 'Robot *'
  | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe8440809c0 <col:5> 'Robot *' <LValueToRValue>
  |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fe844080998 <col:5> 'Robot *' lvalue ImplicitParam 0x7fe8440808d8 'self' 'Robot *'
  |-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080ac8 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue
  | `-StringLiteral 0x7fe844080a48 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue "123"
  |-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080b60 <col:18> 'char *'
  | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe844080b10 <col:18> 'char *' <ArrayToPointerDecay>
  |   `-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080ac8 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue
  |     `-StringLiteral 0x7fe844080a48 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue "123"
  `-ObjCMessageExpr 0x7fe844080b28 <col:10> 'void' selector=setModel:
    |-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080a78 <col:5> 'Robot *'
    | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe8440809c0 <col:5> 'Robot *' <LValueToRValue>
    |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x7fe844080998 <col:5> 'Robot *' lvalue ImplicitParam 0x7fe8440808d8 'self' 'Robot *'
    `-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080b60 <col:18> 'char *'
      `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fe844080b10 <col:18> 'char *' <ArrayToPointerDecay>
        `-OpaqueValueExpr 0x7fe844080ac8 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue
          `-StringLiteral 0x7fe844080a48 <col:18> 'char [4]' lvalue "123"
```

The structure of the last ObjCMessageExpr is similar to the getter case.

It seems that if you traverse the tree and find all **DeclRefExpr** nodes that refer to an ImplicitParam (ImplicitParamDecl) named self, you'll find all occurences of "self".

Comment: Thanks, that really helped!